# PPA- what are Regular, Random, Normal and Clustered?

Tags: spatial, point-process

In Point Pattern Analysis a particular dataset can be one of four, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_pattern_analysis): Clustered, Normal, Random or Regular.

The four:

[image: Clustered Normal Random Regular]

What is the name of those four options? Point Patterns? Point Processes?

Comment: It would help if you could provide some more content for those not experienced with this topic, and possibly some applicable code.

Comment: Hi Giuseppe I've added the diagram of the four options

Comment: Well done: (+1)

Comment: According to the first words in your question, these are "point patterns."  There seems to be little else to add.

Comment: thanks @whuber can you please answer hopefully with reference i'll accept

Comment: You already provided the Wikipedia reference!  As far as I can tell, there's nothing to answer.

Comment: Oh, now I see. A few things. The wikipedia page does not explicitly say these are "point patterns". For example the terms normal and regular do not appear at all. The term 'clustered' appears in different contexts: "clustered process", "clustered point patterns". The term Random seems to be confused with CSR there. Another issue is the credibility of Wikipedia, I'm not sure this can be called a reference nor its 2011 single reference for this article.